# How to delete a field from UI by clicking its respective delete icon - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, field

[image][image]I have couple of input fields created using matInput. I have followed parent child structure to create this.I have a delete icon corresponding to each input field.If i click the delete icon, the respective field has to be removed from UI. Attached the image for reference and below is the code .
I have income-field.component which is the child component, and employee-details which is the parent component. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks!!

income-field.component.html

```
<div  [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <mat-form-field >
    <div class="delete-icon" *ngIf="showDeleteIcon" (click)="removeIncomeField($event, i)">
      <img src="/assets/icons/delete_income.png"></div>

    <input matInput [(value)]="value" [placeholder]="placeholder" type="number" (input)="change($event.target.value)"
      [formControlName]="name" />
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

income-field.component.ts:


export class IncomeFieldComponent {
  @Input() placeholder;
  @Input() value;
  @Input() name;
  @Input() showDeleteIcon;
  @Output() textValue = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() deleteIncomeField= new EventEmitter();
  @Input() parentForm: FormControl;
  isActive = false;

  removeIncomeField(event: any) {
    this.deleteIncomeField.emit(event);
  }
change(value) {
    this.value = +value;
    this.textValue.emit(this.value);
  }
}

employee-details.component.html:

  <app-income-field placeholder="Business income"  [value]=""
            type="number" name="businessIncome" (textValue)="getTextValue($event, 'businessIncome')" [showDeleteIcon]="true"
              [parentForm]="employee_info_form" id="business" (deleteIncomeField)="deleteSelectedField($event)">
            </app-income-field>

  <app-income-field placeholder="Real estate" [showDeleteIcon]="true" [value]=""
              type="number" name="realEstateIncome" (deleteIncomeField)="deleteSelectedField($event)" (textValue)="getTextValue($event, 'realEstateIncome')"
              [parentForm]="additional_info_form">
            </app-income-field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of at least two angular ways to do this:

### Remove with `*ngIf`

```
export class EmployeeDetailsComponent {
  public showBusinessIncome = true;
  public showRealEstate = true;

  removeIncomeField(input: number) {
    if(input === 1) {
       this.showBusinessIncome = false;
    }
    else if (input === 2) {
       this.showRealEstate = false;
    }
  }
}
```

And in html

```
  <app-income-field placeholder="Business income"  [value]=""
            type="number" name="businessIncome" (textValue)="getTextValue($event, 'businessIncome')" [showDeleteIcon]="true" *ngIf="showBusinessIncome"
              [parentForm]="employee_info_form" id="business" (deleteIncomeField)="deleteSelectedField(1)">
            </app-income-field>

  <app-income-field placeholder="Real estate" [showDeleteIcon]="true" [value]=""
              type="number" name="realEstateIncome" *ngIf="showRealEstate" (deleteIncomeField)="deleteSelectedField(2)" (textValue)="getTextValue($event, 'realEstateIncome')"
              [parentForm]="additional_info_form">
            </app-income-field>
```

### Make the `IncomeFieldComponent` custom control and handle with reactive forms

This is a bit more complicated to get into, but I would propose to followi [this material guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control)

Then you will be able to remove the control properly from the `FormGroup`

[Angular form group guide](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

```
const myForm = new FormGroup({
  businessIncome: new FormControl('businessIncome'),
  realEaste: new FormControl('realEstate')
});
```

```
this.myForm.removeControl('businessIncome', null);
```

Comment: In the first example using *ngIf, what is input: numnber and how are you checking the condition input==1..in my case , console.log(input) is different. Attached the log of console.log.

Comment: I cannot accept your answer as the solution didnt work for me..:(

Comment: Thanks you very much .. I tried the update solution using *ngIf and it works perfectly fine.:)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how easiest the solution will be to achieve this. But I have managed to achieve the solution. This might not be the best answer as I had to write  2 separate functions for 2 fields. However the below code works , I am not happy with multiple lines of code. Any refactoring possible on the solution is much appreciated. Thanks!!

income.component.html:

```
<div  [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <mat-form-field >
   <div class="delete-icon" *ngIf="showDeleteIconForBusiness" (click)="removeBusinessField($event)">
      <img src="/assets/icons/delete_income.png"></div>
<!--added another div for real estate field-->
<div class="delete-icon" *ngIf="showDeleteIconForRealestate" (click)="removeRealEstateField($event)">
        <img src="/assets/icons/delete_income.png"></div>

    <input matInput [(value)]="value" [placeholder]="placeholder" type="number" (input)="change($event.target.value)"
      [formControlName]="name" />
  </mat-form-field>
</div>


export class IncomeFieldComponent {
  @Input() placeholder;
  @Input() value;
  @Input() name;
   @Input() showDeleteIconForBusiness;
  @Input() showDeleteIconForRealestate
  @Output() textValue = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() deleteBusinessField= new EventEmitter();
  @Output() deleteRealestateField=new EventEmitter();
  @Input() parentForm: FormControl;
  isActive = false;

 removeBusinessField(event: any) {
    this.deleteBusinessField.emit(event);
  }
  removeRealEstateField(event:any) {
    this.deleteRealestateField.emit(event);
  }
change(value) {
    this.value = +value;
    this.textValue.emit(this.value);
  }
}

employee-details.component.html:

  <app-income-field placeholder="Business income"  [value]=""
            type="number" name="businessIncome" (textValue)="getTextValue($event, 'businessIncome')" [showDeleteIconForBusiness]="true"
              [parentForm]="employee_info_form" (deleteBusinessField)="deleteBusinessField()">
            </app-income-field>

  <app-income-field placeholder="Real estate" [showDeleteIconForRealestate]="true" [value]=""
              type="number" name="realEstateIncome" (deleteRealestateField)="deleteRealestateField()" (textValue)="getTextValue($event, 'realEstateIncome')"
              [parentForm]="additional_info_form">
            </app-income-field>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add for each field specific id like this:

`<mat-form-field id="name>...</mat-form-field>`
and then delete the field with pure javascript with

`document.getElementById('name').remove()`

but IMO just add another variables to hidden the element then check the variables when the save function happen.

Comment: document.getElementById().remove() has no place in Angular.

Comment: why? you can inject @Inject(DOCUMENT) document  and use it

Comment: and yes alternative is @ViewChild

Comment: Just because you can, it doesn't mean you should. Let Angular manage the DOM, and let your code manage the model.